# Streaming to Sony NS510 from a windows 10 pc over the LAN

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming

I have a Sony NS510 wireless speaker and in windows 7 i was able to stream music from my windows pc to it via the "windows digital controller" application. It is still available in Windows 10, however i think its a bit flaky as it seems to play a couple of tune, then freezes.

I am wondering if VLC will be able to do a similar thing, but i am not sure how to do this. i believe the speaker supports DLNA if that is of any help